# $M:\mathbb{R}^{5\times5} T: M\to M$ denote the operator $T (A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$, find the kernel.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, transformation

My question is:

Let $M = \mathbb{R}^{5\times 5}$ and let $T:M \to M$ denote the operator $$T (A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$$ where superscript $T$ is the matrix transpose. How can I find kernel, range, nullity, rank, real eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Firstly,
I checked that $T$ preserves sums and multiplication by scalars, so it is a linear map.
$T(A+B)=T(A)+T(B) T(c.A)=c.T(A)$.
If this matrix was $2\times 2$, I could have let $A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
and then calculated $$T(A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$$ to find kernel, range, nullity, rank.

But this matrix is $(5\times 5)$. So I can't draw like $2\times 2$ matrix and could not calculate
$$T (A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$$
Can you suggest another way for me to calculate these values(kernel, range, nullity, rank, real eigenvalues and eigenvectors)?

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

(1) I leave it to you to argue that the kernel of $T$ is the subspace of symmetric matrices. It is not difficult to show that the space of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices has dimension $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Since $n=5$, $\text{dim(ker}(T)) = \frac{5 \cdot 6}{2} = 15$.

(2) $T(A)$ must be a matrix with zeros along its diagonal (why?). That tells you something about the range. Also, by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, $\text{rank}(T) = \text{dim}(M) - \text{dim(ker}(T)) = 25 - 15 = 10$. I will also leave it to you to give a more explicit description of the range based on these facts.

(3) You can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors by considering the equation $T(A) = \lambda A$ for $A \neq \mathbf{0}$, that is

$$\frac{1}{2}(A- A^\top) = \lambda A \iff (\frac{1}{2} - \lambda)A =  \frac{1}{2} A^\top$$.

Since the diagonal elements of $A$ and $A^\top$ are the same, we must have $(\frac{1}{2} - \lambda) a_{ii} = \frac{1}{2}a_{ii} \implies -\lambda a_{ii} = 0$ for all $i$. This means that $\lambda = 0$ is the only possible eigenvalue, whose eigenspace is the kernel.

Comment: Hi I can say ker T= T(A)=0 1/2(A-A^T)=0 so A^T=A right?But I couldnt calculate as a value. then eigenvalues is 1/2?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. $T(A) \implies A = A^\top$, which is what I wrote, namely that $\text{ker} (T) = \{ A \in M \, | \, A = A^\top \}$, i.e. the set of symmetric matrices. I don't know what you mea by "as a value". You are asking for the kernel, i.e. the set of all matrices that $T$ map to $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Then can we say that rank nulity teorem rank(A)+nullity(A)=n  n =5 nullity=1 kernel=1 so rank(A)=5-1=4 ?                      eigenvalues is 1/2? then how can I find eigenvectors?

Comment: Remember that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{5 \times 5}$ is $25$. I have now expanded my answer to give you some more hints and I have corrected some minor errors that were there. I hope you find it more helpful now.